# Is there a Razor helper that allows you to create a url with a string and object

Tags: c#, url, razor

I need to generate a url. I have a dynamic variety of get parameters that i need to form a nice url from... I have a base url and would like to have an object...

```
("/my/custom/url", new { customParam = "toot", toopy = "foop" })
```

The above would create:

```
/my/custom/url?customParam=toot&toopy=foop
```

I do not have an action or controller to map it to and thus does not work with `Html.Action` or `Url.Action`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't out of the box solution for this if you don't have the `Controller` and `Action`.

If you want a helper for traditional URLs, consider making your own custom `HTML Helper`: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Comment: Thanks mate... Just thought it might be something included :)

Comment: You're welcome. :) I assume you can find already made solutions with a custom helper for this since it is not an unknown subject, but I was unable to pinpoint my google search towards anything useful than a custom `HTML Helper` guide. Good luck!